# Best program to make graph, charts, line in 2D

Tags: linear-algebra, graphing-functions

I love working with lines, graphs, charts, etc. I have been searching for a program in which I can make them; I have found some only for graph and some only for charts, and was wondering if there is any program which offers both. Here is what I have in mind for [graphs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h1wIX.gif) and for [charts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hrm3A.png).

Comment: That looks like Geogebra output. Why not use that?

Comment: Geogebra  don't have charts how i saw it

Comment: If you know python, you can probably do everything you want with matplotlib.  Look at this [example](https://matplotlib.org/gallery/text_labels_and_annotations/date.html#sphx-glr-gallery-text-labels-and-annotations-date-py)

Comment: Excel is a good and common way to get graphs and charts

Comment: Check out [Asymptote](http://asymptote.sourceforge.net/).